# Split string by right closing parentheses

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string in java based on brackets with the possibility that there are nested brackets, example:

```
"{one two {three}}{one {two} {{three}}}"
```

what I would like to get is an array with

```
array [0] = {one two {three}}

array [1] = {one {two} {{three}}}
```

I tried using the `\ {(. *?) \}` Regex but I get substrings like

```
{one two {Three}
```

which do not take into account which is the correct closing parenthesis

How can I do it?

Comment: Is there arbitrary nesting or do you know max depth? [See demo for max 2 level deep](https://regex101.com/r/N3jJ0i/1/)

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong and there is no space between the 2 groups of brackets.
No unfortunately I don't know the depth limit.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/D5mj9i, no need for a regex.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with a regex (alone), as you are trying to recognize a non-regular grammar. Just iterate over the string, while maintaining a counter representing the current nesting depth. Whenever you hit a right bracket and the depth goes down to zero, output the portion of the substring since the last time the depth hit zero.

Answer (score -1):

First try introducing a new line between consecutive right and left parentheses - that is - `}[ ]*{`.
Then you can split on the new line ( may need to remove existing new lines before replacing if or as required ).

Comment: That doesn’t work with nested braces. Consider `{{one}{two}}`. And there’s no need for the newline stuff.

Comment: Idea was to answer for specific example. However even there it would have failed for `{two} {{three}}`. So in any case its not something that was doable.